# GWT-APACHE CXF header

Tags: gwt, jax-rs, cxf

I have a CXF JAX-RS service and a GWT MVP4G presenter.
I call the service with the RequestBuilder and set Content-Type header to application/json.

But in the server side REST method do not call .

REST code is :

```
 class PlayerService{
 @POST
 @Path("addplayer")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 String createOrSaveNewPLayerInfo(PlayerType playerType);
}
```

GWT code:

```
 RequestBuilder rq = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url)
 rq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 rq.sendRequest(s, new RequestCallback() {
 @Override
 public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
 LOGGER.info(">" + response.getStatusCode() + "<");
 }
 @Override
 public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
 LOGGER.info(">>" + exception.getMessage() + "<<");
 }
 });
```

Comment: Do you get a 404 or do you have an exception on the server side?

Comment: No . request received to the server and request builder get this message: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that your GWT application is running on the Jetty server and your service on a Tomcat server. In this case you have two different ports: 8080 & 8888. Calling the service on 8080 will be blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

To solve this, you can switch off the policy (look for CORS). Bad idea.

Instead run your GWT application inside a Tomcat. In this case you will not have any problems with the SOP.

To set up a external server with GWT take a look [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT).

Comment: I use embed Jetty in CXF and GWT.I run CXF at 127.0.0.1:9000 and GWT

Comment: at 127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: Both applications should run the same port. Otherwise the Same Origin Policy of the browser will block the communication. You have to use an external server.

Comment: More informations: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html

Comment: I added CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter  to the server and everything is OK.